# Rendering datatable column with ajax and jsf

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, datatable

I have a datatable listing some items with several details :

```
<h:dataTable id="versionInterfaces_datatable"
        styleClass="datatable" rowClasses="odd,even"
        value="#{versionToolManager.version.interfaces}"
        var="lInterface">

   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Interface Name</f:facet>
      <h:commandLink id="versionInterfacesName_columnLink"
            value="#{lInterface.name}"
            action="#{interfaceManager.consult}">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener
              target="#{interfaceManager.interfaceEntity}"
              value="#{lInterface}" />
      </h:commandLink>
      <h:outputText id="versionInterfacesName_column" value="#{lInterface.name}" />
   </h:column>

   <h:column id="interfaceVersions_column">
       <f:facet name="header">Interface Version(s)</f:facet>
       <ui:repeat value="#{lInterface.versionsInterface}" var="lVersionI"
              varStatus="lStatus">
           <h:outputText rendered="#{lVersionI.versionsTools.contains(versionToolManager.version)}" value=" #{lVersionI.name} | " />
       </ui:repeat>
   </h:column>

   <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">Interface Description</f:facet>
      <h:outputText id="versionInterfacesDescription_column"
           value="#{lInterface.description}" />
   </h:column>
```

and then I have a button calling a modal view allowing to add items :

```
<h:commandButton id="#{id}OpenModal_button"
   value="#{openButtonValue}"
  onclick="document.getElementById('#{formId}:#{modal_panel}').style.display='block'; return false;" />
<br />
```

when closing this modal view, I try to "refresh" the datatable to see the items added :

```
    <h:commandButton id="#{id}CloseModal_button"
      value="#{closeButtonValue}">
      <f:ajax execute="@this"
        render="#{renderOnClose} #{formId}:#{modal_panel}" />
    </h:commandButton>
```

But the columns of my datatable are not all updated, the column "Interface Version(s)" is empty for the new lines corresponding to the new items even though when I save, they have been well added.

Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `<f:ajax execute="@this" ...`

use `<f:ajax execute="@all" ...`

Comment: thanks for your answer but it didn't change anything, the column doesn't update. But if you think it's about the scope of the rendering maybe I should add something to the render attribute?

Answer (score 0):

So I succeed to solve my problem but it wasn't a problem about the syntax but a bad use of the model and beans structure. Without going into details, I was trying to reach data which weren't linked to the corresponding items.